# How to print image in jquery from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i try this

```
$.each(json, function(i, mhs) {
      $('<tr/>', {
        html: [$('<td/>', {
          text: mhs.nim
        }), $('<td/>', {
          text: mhs.nama
        }), $('<td/>', {
          text: mhs.alamat
        }), $('<td/>', {
          text: document.write(mhs.foto)
        })]
      }).appendTo('#mhsTable tbody')
    })
```

but `mhs.foto` out of table

this my json data, i make this in array

```
[{"nim":"E1E113aaa","nama":"AAAAA","alamat":"Jl. aaaa","foto":"<img src=aaa.jpg width=100px height=100px>"},{"nim":"E1E113aaa","nama":"AAAAA","alamat":"Jl. aaaa","foto":"<img src=aaa.jpg width=100px height=100px>"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

To insert HTML in to an element use jQuery's `html()` method. `text()` will encode the data and `document.write` should never be used. Try this:

```js
var json = [{
  "nim": "E1E113aaa",
  "nama": "AAAAA",
  "alamat": "Jl. aaaa",
  "foto": "<img src=\"aaa.jpg\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\">"
}, {
  "nim": "E1E113aaa",
  "nama": "AAAAA",
  "alamat": "Jl. aaaa",
  "foto": "<img src=\"aaa.jpg\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\">"
}]


$.each(json, function(i, mhs) {
  $('<tr/>', {
    html: [$('<td/>', {
      text: mhs.nim
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: mhs.nama
    }), $('<td/>', {
      text: mhs.alamat
    }), $('<td/>', {
      html: mhs.foto // note the use of 'html' here
    })]
  }).appendTo('#mhsTable tbody')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mhsTable">
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could simplify this using an inner loop and use `html()`

```
var $tbody=$('#mhsTable tbody');// cache tbody once instead of search dom each iteration
$.each(json, function(i, mhs) {
   var $row= $('<tr>');
   $.each( ['nim','nama', 'alamat'],function(_, key) {
       $row.append( $('<td>').html(mhs[key]) );
   });
   $tbody.append($row);
});
```